# Qlik View Google Map Extension Template error

Tags: google-maps, qlikview

I am new to the Qlik View tool. I have embedded an extension called Google Maps API v3. I have supplied the API Key in the configuration. But Still, when i select the longitude and latitude, it refreshes but the location is not changed in the map. And I'm still unaware of the term Measure 1.

[Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Vk6.png)

Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

1. I had serious problem with that extension and finally decided just to use different one which is using OpenStreeMap
2. The one which I am using is quickMap (and can help you with that) I am included it as zip (I zipped just folder C:\ProgramData\QlikTech\QlikViewServer\Extensions\Objects\quickMap as I odn't have original installation) I put it here https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am4ZTQ8qcLwRsmpZAliHBF1_ayQx
3. Most plugins works only in webmode:

[image: web mode]

4. There are paid geo extensions to Qlikview which cost a bit but with them there are no such a problems.
5. Here is example properties of extension used by me when description is for example "Lombardia;Milano;9.189982,45.4642035"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I installed Quick map. Can you give me a quick overview to map the latitude and longitude? Or just the basic configuration of the extension. :)

Comment: as a dimension I am using field with province and city and lang/log seperated by collons. Example value: Lombardia;Milano;9.189982,45.4642035

Comment: and as a second dimension I am using only long/lat as for example 9.189982,45.4642035